# PostgreSQL - how to work with?

Tags: mysql, database, macos, postgresql, terminal

I have installed PostgreSQL to my Mac OS X (10.6), specifically [the EnterpriseDB](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/). In the applications was created the folder **PostgreSQL 9.1** and there is **SQL Shell (psql).app**. After opening this app is opened terminal window, where is on the command line **Server [localhost]:**.

I am a bit confused of that, how can I work/log-in to this DB system? I am habit on MySQL, where I just type to the terminal window **mysql -u username -p password** and everything is prepared to work, but here I am a bit confused... How can I log-in to PostgreSQL database>

**EDIT**

```
locate psql | grep /bin

WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can login with psql. You don't need a password, if your unix-account name matches the db-account name and the sever is on localhost. At least that's the default in postgreSQL (check for ident in pg_hba.conf).

If you want to use a different db-user, check "psql --help".

Comment: when I type `psql`, I'll get `-bash: psql: command not found`. When I try to `run locate psql | grep /bin`, I got the error, that I posted to the original post (longer statement). How to fix that?

Comment: try this to find the binary: find / -name psql